# Implementing horizontalList inside a vertical list in android

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontallist

I have made a custom Horizontal List view which works fine. I then implemented the same horizontal list inside a ListView control. But when I run the same, all I get is a blank output. The list does not seem to poupulate.

On debugging I found, that the adapter which was added to the list view contain the items(Horizontal lists).

So, the problem is clearly not of items not populating properly, its of the view not rendered properly.

Here is the code for vertical list view:

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.twowaylistview.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/lstHor"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </com.example.twowaylistview.HorizontalListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is XML for individual item in the horizontal list

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgListItem"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
      ..            />

   ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

let me know if you need the java code. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After Android L Developer Preview published, Google supply a new View called `RecyclerView` which can replace `ListView` and `GridView`, it makes it easier to make a horizontal list, so I update my answer here.

We don't need to use any library anymore at this time, `RecyclerView` is just enough. Here is the code which I make a horizontal list by `RecyclerView` (I am not trying to explain detailed usage of `RecyclerView`):

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<List<String>> mDataList;

    private RecyclerView mVerticalList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prepareData();
        initListView();
    }

    private void prepareData() {
        mDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        int vItemCount = 25;
        int hItemCount = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < vItemCount; i++) {
            List<String> hList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < hItemCount; j++) {
                hList.add("Item." + j);
            }
            mDataList.add(hList);
        }
    }

    private void initListView() {
        mVerticalList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.vertical_list);
        mVerticalList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        VerticalAdapter verticalAdapter = new VerticalAdapter();
        verticalAdapter.setData(mDataList);
        mVerticalList.setAdapter(verticalAdapter);
    }

    private static class VerticalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private List<List<String>> mDataList;

        public VerticalAdapter() {
        }

        public void setData(List<List<String>> data) {
            mDataList = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private class HorizontalListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView title;
            private RecyclerView horizontalList;
            private HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter;

            public HorizontalListViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                Context context = itemView.getContext();
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                horizontalList = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_horizontal_list);
                horizontalList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
                horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter();
                horizontalList.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vertical_list_item, parent, false);
            HorizontalListViewHolder holder = new HorizontalListViewHolder(itemView);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder rawHolder, int position) {
            HorizontalListViewHolder holder = (HorizontalListViewHolder) rawHolder;
            holder.title.setText("Horizontal List No." + position);
            holder.horizontalAdapter.setData(mDataList.get(position));
            holder.horizontalAdapter.setRowIndex(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataList.size();
        }
    }

    private static class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private List<String> mDataList;
        private int mRowIndex = -1;
        private int[] mColors = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.DKGRAY};

        public HorizontalAdapter() {
        }

        public void setData(List<String> data) {
            if (mDataList != data) {
                mDataList = data;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        public void setRowIndex(int index) {
            mRowIndex = index;
        }

        private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView text;

            public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(mItemClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list_item, parent, false);
            ItemViewHolder holder = new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder rawHolder, int position) {
            ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) rawHolder;
            holder.text.setText(mDataList.get(position));
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mColors[position % mColors.length]);
            holder.itemView.setTag(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataList.size();
        }

        private View.OnClickListener mItemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int columnIndex = (int) v.getTag();
                int rowIndex = mRowIndex;

                String text = String.format("rowIndex:%d ,columnIndex:%d", rowIndex, columnIndex);
                showToast(v.getContext(), text);
                Log.d("test", text);
            }
        };
    }

    private static Toast sToast;

    public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {
        if (sToast != null) {
            sToast.cancel();
        }
        sToast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        sToast.show();
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/vertical_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`horizontal_list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`vertical_list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_horizontal_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

update at 2015-05-20

### Old Answer:

I have used [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) to show horizontal lists in a vertical listview just like you. Here is my vertical and horizontal  listview adapter code .It works fine for me, all views are reusable, all the rows scroll individually. I hope this may help you.

```
public class RecommendAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
    OnItemClickListener {
public static final String TAG = "RecommendAppAdapter";

//Vertical list data
private Map<String, List<RecommendApp>> mMapData = new TreeMap<String, List<RecommendApp>>();

private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = null;

//Vertical list adapter
public RecommendAppAdapter(Context context) {
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return mMapData == null || mMapData.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        return mMapData.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//Get horizental list data
@Override
public List<RecommendApp> getItem(int position) {
    if (!isEmpty() && isAvaliablePostion(position)) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, List<RecommendApp>>> entries = mMapData
                .entrySet().iterator();
        int i = 0;
        Entry<String, List<RecommendApp>> entry = null;
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            entry = entries.next();
            if (i == position) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    ItemAdapter innerListAdapter = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_recommend_app, null);
        //Some views in vertical list
        holder.type = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_rec_app_type_name);
        //Get horizental list view
        holder.hListView = (TwoWayView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_rec_app_list);
        //Bind adapter on horizental list
        innerListAdapter = new ItemAdapter();
        holder.hListView.setAdapter(innerListAdapter);
        //Bind item click listener on horizental list
        holder.hListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        innerListAdapter = (ItemAdapter) holder.hListView.getAdapter();
    }
    //Get horizental list data
    List<RecommendApp> itemList = getItem(position);

    holder.type.setText(itemList.get(0).getTypeName());

    //Deliver horizental list adapter data
    innerListAdapter.setData(itemList);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.item_rec_app_list:
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        }
        break;
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = listener;
}

public void setData(Map<String, List<RecommendApp>> data) {
    mMapData.clear();
    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        mMapData.putAll(data);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private boolean isAvaliablePostion(int position) {
    if (position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView type;
    public TwoWayView hListView;
}

//Horizontal list adapter
//All work are just like the normal use of ListView 
private class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Horizontal list data
    private List<RecommendApp> mInnerData = null;

    private FinalBitmap mFinalBitmap = FinalBitmap.create(MyApp
            .getInstance());

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return mInnerData == null || mInnerData.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            return mInnerData.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public RecommendApp getItem(int position) {
        if (position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
            return mInnerData.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderInner holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolderInner();
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_recommend_app_inner, null);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_rec_app_inner_name);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_rec_app_inner_icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderInner) convertView.getTag();
        }
        RecommendApp item = ItemAdapter.this.getItem(position);
        holder.name.setText(item.getAppName());
        mFinalBitmap.display(holder.icon, item.getIcon());
        return convertView;
    }

    public void setData(List<RecommendApp> data) {
        mInnerData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class ViewHolderInner {
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView icon;
    }
}
```

}

## Edit 1

RecommendApp is a POJO which contain data of an item that shows in the horizontal list.

item_recommend_app.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_rec_app_type_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/item_rec_app_type_name_bg"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/item_rec_app_type_name_paddingBottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/item_rec_app_type_name_paddingLeft"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/item_rec_app_type_name_paddingTop"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<com.phonetools.appmanager.widget.TwoWayView
    android:id="@+id/item_rec_app_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

item_recommend_app_inner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/item_rec_app_inner_padding" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_rec_app_inner_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_rec_app_inner_icon_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/item_rec_app_inner_icon_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_rec_app_inner_name"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_rec_app_inner_icon_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />
```

RecommendApp.java:

```
public class RecommendApp {
public RecommendApp() {
}


private String packageName;


private String appName;


private String versionName;


private float size;


private String icon;


private int typeId;


private String typeName;


private String installLink;


private String description;


private float ratingScore;


private long installedSum;
```

}

Comment: what is RecommendApp??

Comment: can you also post the XML

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how you got OnItemClickListener on main listview?

Comment: I have the same doubt like umesh. How to implement onitemclicklistner on main listview, which should return horizontal list position?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list view to show horizontal and vertical scrolling list. You can use table layout.
Below is my code in which both side scrolling is performing well.

Also you can customize it according your needs.

Create MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TableRow.LayoutParams wrapWrapTableRowParams = new     TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int[] fixedColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20};
    int[] scrollableColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30};
    int fixedRowHeight = 50;
    int fixedHeaderHeight = 60;

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    //header (fixed vertically)
    TableLayout header = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_header);
    row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 1", fixedColumnWidths[0], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 2", fixedColumnWidths[1], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 3", fixedColumnWidths[2], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 4", fixedColumnWidths[3], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 5", fixedColumnWidths[4], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 6", fixedColumnWidths[5], fixedHeaderHeight));
    header.addView(row);

    //header (fixed horizontally)

    TableLayout fixedColumn = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixed_column);

    //rest of the table (within a scroll view)

    TableLayout scrollablePart = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollable_part);

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
       TextView fixedView = makeTableRowWithText("row number " + i,   scrollableColumnWidths[0], fixedRowHeight);

        fixedColumn.addView(fixedView);
        row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 2", scrollableColumnWidths[1], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 3", scrollableColumnWidths[2], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 4", scrollableColumnWidths[3], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 5", scrollableColumnWidths[4], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 6", scrollableColumnWidths[5], fixedRowHeight));
        scrollablePart.addView(row);
   }
}

//util method
private TextView recyclableTextView;
 public TextView makeTableRowWithText(String text, int widthInPercentOfScreenWidth, int   fixedHeightInPixels) {
int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
recyclableTextView = new TextView(this);
recyclableTextView.setText(text);
recyclableTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
recyclableTextView.setTextSize(20);
recyclableTextView.setWidth(widthInPercentOfScreenWidth * screenWidth / 100);
recyclableTextView.setHeight(fixedHeightInPixels);
return recyclableTextView;
  }
}
```

Create activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/fillable_area">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/fillable_area">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/fixed_column"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this i'll solve your needs.

Thanks

Comment: i want all the rows to scroll individually.

Comment: I think it will possible. See the Xml here i put view into scroll view. And then also take table layout into "HorizontalScrollView".

Comment: You can cutomize it for row also.