# Horizontal pager inside vertical list in android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement a Horizontal Pager inside a vertical list view. I am able to implement Horizontal List(TwoWayList) inside Vertical list.
[Implementing horizontalList inside a vertical list in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060459/implementing-horizontallist-inside-a-vertical-list-in-android)

But when I implement the same with a [Horizontal Pager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) inside vertical list, I am getting an error as: `ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.`

This works fine when I fix the height and width of the layout but I want the width of the Pager to fill_parent.

How can I implement it, and also Is this approach of using horizontal pager inside vertical list correct? Or Is there an easy way to do so.

Comment: Have you tried android.support.v4.view.ViewPager instead of Horizontal Pager?

Comment: this doesn't work with the adapter