# How to create an Horizontal List View inside of a Vertical List View?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, horizontallistview

I have succeed to add a List View inside of a vertical List View. 
My Problem is with the horizontal list view. Can somebody explain to me how I should create an horizontal ListView? 
Should i switch to a Recycler View to create an horizontal List ? Or I stick with a ListView?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: RecyclerView is the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RecyclerView with Horizontal LinearLayout as a item view of vertical RecyclerView with Vertical LinearLayoutManager. Yeah if you are creating your views right now from the scratch, always use Recycler View instead of ListView onwards.

Answer (score 0):

you need to just inflate layout inside getView if you had still issues then look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060459/implementing-horizontallist-inside-a-vertical-list-in-android).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list_item, null,false);

    LinearLayout mainLinnerLayout=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);

     for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
         View additionView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_layout_file, null,false);
         LinearLayout innerLinnerLayout=(LinearLayout)additionView.findViewById(R.id.inner_layout);

         // If the width varies for each innerLinnerLayout, then remove the if block & always calculate padding value
         // padding is an integer initialized to -1 in the constructor
         if (padding == -1) {
             int width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
             innerLinnerLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
             padding = width - additionView.getMeasuredWidth();
         }
         // I've set padding to right only, but you could center it by giving left and right padding of value=(padding/2)
         innerLinnerLayout.setPadding(0, 0, padding, 0);
         mainLinnerLayout.addView(innerLinnerLayout);
    } 
    return convertView;
}
```